# Where to download a lot of digits of pi?

Tags: download

Where could I find a large amount of digits of pi? I have already calculated 3.14 billion using PiFast (works well under wine).

I don't care about slow download speeds.

Comment: Do you need it for some even remotely practical purpose, or just for ... ? I can't see the point, so I'm just curious.

Comment: @Idigas: Don't you ever make pi?

Comment: Soon's i can find the algorithm for calculating pi, i'll write something up to calculate as many as you want...

Comment: Go ahead and try accepting a new answer to your question.  The original accepted answer had a single link that no longer exists, so it has been deleted.  Go ahead and flag the question if you have any questions for the moderators.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know you say you don't care, but I seriously suspect **your cpu can calculate them *faster* than your network card is capable of downloading them.**

Given the last digit and the current state of the calculator used to generate it, the next digit can be found in constant time.  It doesn't get progressively harder like finding the next prime does.

Comment: Yes, but it is a lot of cpu time to dedicate, and I would rather dedicate some bandwidth rather than all that cpu time.

Comment: @Joel: by the way, can you show a pointer to an algorithm for that? (Yeah, I know that's more like SO content, but since we're here...)

Comment: http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/PiProgram/pifast.html

Comment: The math is beyond me, but read way down in wikipedia and one of the series is said to "deliver 14 digits per term".

Comment: Sorry, wrong link: http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/PiProgram/algo.html, It was in frames

Comment: @Joel That would be the Chudnovsky formula

Comment: 5 minutes to calculate 100m decimals on my reasonably new laptop (using `pi` package on non-virtual Ubuntu), 10 seconds to download the same as a 57MB file. Conclusion: calculating is 30 times slower than downloading.

Comment: That's simply not true.

Answer (score 4):

Adding on to Joel's comment, [SuperPi](http://files.extremeoverclocking.com/file.php?f=36) is one of the most popular tools for this. It's also used for stress testing.

Comment: PiFast is faster.

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu, you can `sudo apt-get install pi`

and then:

`$ pi 100
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067`

It calculates arbitrary precision given the number of digits to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Python to calculate it, here's an extremely fast method (using Python and the gmpy2 library):

http://www.craig-wood.com/nick/articles/pi-chudnovsky/

Here's the code with a small fix:

```py
"""
Python3 program to calculate Pi using python long integers, binary
splitting and the Chudnovsky algorithm

See: http://www.craig-wood.com/nick/articles/pi-chudnovsky/ for more
info

Nick Craig-Wood <nick@craig-wood.com>
"""

import math
from gmpy2 import mpz
from time import time
import gmpy2

def pi_chudnovsky_bs(digits):
    """
    Compute int(pi * 10**digits)

    This is done using Chudnovsky's series with binary splitting
    """
    C = 640320
    C3_OVER_24 = C**3 // 24
    def bs(a, b):
        """
        Computes the terms for binary splitting the Chudnovsky infinite series

        a(a) = +/- (13591409 + 545140134*a)
        p(a) = (6*a-5)*(2*a-1)*(6*a-1)
        b(a) = 1
        q(a) = a*a*a*C3_OVER_24

        returns P(a,b), Q(a,b) and T(a,b)
        """
        if b - a == 1:
            # Directly compute P(a,a+1), Q(a,a+1) and T(a,a+1)
            if a == 0:
                Pab = Qab = mpz(1)
            else:
                Pab = mpz((6*a-5)*(2*a-1)*(6*a-1))
                Qab = mpz(a*a*a*C3_OVER_24)
            Tab = Pab * (13591409 + 545140134*a) # a(a) * p(a)
            if a & 1:
                Tab = -Tab
        else:
            # Recursively compute P(a,b), Q(a,b) and T(a,b)
            # m is the midpoint of a and b
            m = (a + b) // 2
            # Recursively calculate P(a,m), Q(a,m) and T(a,m)
            Pam, Qam, Tam = bs(a, m)
            # Recursively calculate P(m,b), Q(m,b) and T(m,b)
            Pmb, Qmb, Tmb = bs(m, b)
            # Now combine
            Pab = Pam * Pmb
            Qab = Qam * Qmb
            Tab = Qmb * Tam + Pam * Tmb
        return Pab, Qab, Tab
    # how many terms to compute
    DIGITS_PER_TERM = math.log10(C3_OVER_24/6/2/6)
    N = int(digits/DIGITS_PER_TERM + 1)
    # Calclate P(0,N) and Q(0,N)
    P, Q, T = bs(0, N)
    one_squared = mpz(10)**(2*digits)
    #sqrtC = (10005*one_squared).sqrt()
    sqrtC = gmpy2.isqrt(10005*one_squared)
    return (Q*426880*sqrtC) // T

# The last 5 digits or pi for various numbers of digits
check_digits = {
        100 : 70679,
       1000 :  1989,
      10000 : 75678,
     100000 : 24646,
    1000000 : 58151,
   10000000 : 55897,
}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    digits = 100
    pi = pi_chudnovsky_bs(digits)
    print(pi)
    #raise SystemExit
    for log10_digits in range(1,9):
        digits = 10**log10_digits
        start =time()
        pi = pi_chudnovsky_bs(digits)
        print("chudnovsky_gmpy_mpz_bs: digits",digits,"time",time()-start)
        if digits in check_digits:
            last_five_digits = pi % 100000
            if check_digits[digits] == last_five_digits:
                print("Last 5 digits %05d OK" % last_five_digits)
                open("%s_pi.txt" % log10_digits, "w").write(str(pi))
            else:
                print("Last 5 digits %05d wrong should be %05d" % (last_five_digits, check_digits[digits]))
```